# Simplicial approximation

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

One of the definition of simplicial approximation says that:
a simplicial map $h:|K|\rightarrow|L|$ is a simplicial approximation of a continuous map $f:|K|\rightarrow|L|$ if and only if 
$$\forall x\in|K|, h(x)\in Car_{L}f(x),$$
where $Car_{L}f(x)$ means the carrier simplex of $f(x)$.

My question is that does this mean that if $f(x)$ is a vertex implies x is also a vertex?

Since it seams that if $f(x)$ is a vertex of $L$, then $h(x)\in Car_{L}f(x)=f(x)\ $ which implies $h(x)=f(x)\ $?

Then if the preimage of a vertex of $L$ under f is at some irrational position of $K$, how is the bisection progress guarantee the existence of a simplicial approximation?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The definition you gave seems to be equivalent to the following
$$
f(|\mathring\sigma|)\subseteq\text{st}(h(\sigma))\ \text{ for all } \sigma\in K
$$
For if $h$ and $f$ satisfy the property given in your question, then if $x\in|\mathring\sigma|$, we have $h(x)\in\text{Car}(f(x))$, and that means $h(\sigma)$ is a face of the simplex whose interior contains $f(x)$, so $f(x)$ is in the open star of $h(\sigma)$. On the other hand, if the above formula holds for every $\sigma\in K$, then given an $x\in|\mathring\sigma|$, it is $f(x)$ in the interior of some simplex with face $h(\sigma)$, and thus $h(x)$ is in the carrier of $f(x)$.

The map $f$ need not map vertices to vertices to have a simplicial approximation. Maybe the simplest example is where $K=\{\{v\}\}$ and $L=\{\{v\},\{w\},\{v,w\}\}$ and $f:|K|\to|L|$ is the map sending $v$ to the point in the middle of the edge $|\{v,w\}|$. Then the inclusion $K\hookrightarrow L$ is a simplicial approximation of $f$.

---

Regarding your edited question: If $f(x)$ is a vertex, then as you correctly noticed $\text{Car}_Lf(x)=f(x)=h(x)$. When $h$ is injective, then this implies that $x$ is a vertex. If $h$ is not injective, then $x$ need not be a vertex. For example $h:L\to K$ (the complexes defined as above), is a simplicial map sending every vertex to $v$, so it also sends $\{v,w\}$ to $\{v\}$, and then $f=|h|$ sends $\frac12v+\frac12w$ to $v$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If f(x) is a vertex then Car(f(x)) is f(x) then h(x) is vertex then x is vertex… what is wrong in this…

Comment: I don't understand. Do you assume that $f(x)$ is a vertex, or do you want to show that $f(x)$ is a vertex?

Comment: assume f(x) is a vertex

Comment: @changer: But in your question you are asking whether this implies that $f(x)$ is a vertex.

Comment: er yeah I may assume it's a subjective map… I will modify it

Comment: @changer: What is true is that when $f$ maps vertices to vertices then $f(x)=h(x)$ for every vertex $x$.

Comment: just wondering what if for some x, f(x) is a vertex…

Comment: thanks！sorry for the trouble… just read this tonight…

Comment: @changer: No problem.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I'm still a little confused. Assume K=L is a triangle ABC(only the boundary) let f be the map that shift the points on the triangle a little bit. Then f is continuous bijective and A B C are no longer vertexes. Suppose f(A')=A, similarly B' C'. Then if we want h to be a simple approximation of f, based on the above discussion, A' B' C' must be vertexes, which the theorem says can be done by taking midpoints. But if A' B'C' is at some irrational position, then no matter how many times you take midpoints, they won't be vertexes… Where do I make a mistake...